# Cypher - Conditional SET

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to update a node in Neo4j, I'm passing variables to the query, and this variables could be null, and I don't want to update the node's property if the variable is null, so I tried this:

```
MATCH (n:address {id: $id})
  SET n = {
    name: COALESCE($name, n.name),
    streetAddress: COALESCE($streetAddress, n.streetAddress),
    build: COALESCE($build, n.build),
    door: COALESCE($door, door),
    latitude: COALESCE($latitude, n.latitude),
    longitude: COALESCE($longitude, n.longitude)
  }

RETURN (n)
```

But it gives the following error:

```
Neo4jError: Expected parameter(s): name, streetAddress, build, latitude, longitude
```

What can I do?

Comment: did you define the parameters? e.g. `$name` with `:param name = "name"`? Or whatever driver you may be using?

Comment: Yes, I did. I already have a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I'm using Javascript with the Neo4j driver for Node.js, I used string interpolation with a function to dynamically build the query:

```
verifyParam(param, paramName) {
  if (param !== null && param !== undefined) return `SET n.${paramName} = ${param}`;

  return '';
}
```

Then in the query string:

```
`
MATCH (n:address {id: $id})

${verifyParam($name, 'name')}
${verifyParam($streetAddress, 'streetAddress')}
${verifyParam($build, 'build')}
${verifyParam($door, 'door')}
${verifyParam($latitude, 'latitude')}
${verifyParam($longitude, 'longitude')}

RETURN (n)
`
```

Maybe is not the best solution, but I didn't found a better solution using only Cypher.